# Apache Service detected with wrong path

Tags: php, apache, web, xampp

Cuando inicializo el Control Panel con XAMPP, recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Apache Service detected with wrong path

¿Qué puedo hacer en este caso?

Este es log de ejecución:

> [main]    Initializing Control Panel
>   [main]    Windows Version:  Pro  64-bit
>   [main]    XAMPP Version: 7.0.18
>   [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
>   [main]    You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
>   [main]    most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
>   [main]    there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
>   [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
>   [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
>   [main]    Checking for prerequisites
>   [main]    All prerequisites found
>   [main]    Initializing Modules
>   [Apache]  Apache Service detected with wrong path
>   [Apache]  Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
>   [Apache]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>   [Apache]  Found Path: "C:\ValeryServer\Apache2.4.1\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>   [Apache]  Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>   [main]    Starting Check-Timer
>   [main]    Control Panel Ready

Comment: por curiosidad, tienes skype instalado?? por alguna razon skype ocupa el puerto 80 trata de deshabilitar el inicio automatico , reinicia tu pc y prueba

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que tenga Apache instalado dos veces, uno de su instalación correcta y otro de una instalación anterior.

Incluso si sólo ves uno, mira la ruta, lo más probable es que sea de una instalación anterior y hace que su instalación no funcione. En cualquier caso, debe eliminar los servicios incorrectos.

HAGA ESTO para todos los servicios XAMPP que encuentre ejecutándose con una ruta incorrecta.

Una vez hecho esto REINICIE LOS SERIVICIOS DEL XAMPP.

Espero haber-le ayudado.

[php](/questions/tagged/php)[xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp)[apache](/questions/tagged/apache)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Obtener la ruta del directorio actual
$directorioActual = Get-Location

# Obtener el nombre del directorio padre
$nombreCarpetaPadre = (Get-Item $directorioActual).Parent.Name

# Mostrar el nombre de la carpeta padre en consola
Write-Host "El nombre de la carpeta padre es: $nombreCarpetaPadre"
```